# Django 1.4 : Create UserProfile+User as an atomic action, Roles, and Admin integration

Tags: django, django-admin, python-2.7, roles, user-profile

I'm building my first real django application which has different user roles and the normal "User signal that creates an UserProfile" approach is falling short. Could you guys help me out ?

To give out more context, here are the requirements from a functional perspective :

- New users are added only from the Admin and will be done by non-tech savy people, so I need a user creation flow thats intuitive and easy.
- Each user has a role (Manager, Employee, Salesman, etc) with different needs and fields.
- The user list needs to show both User Information and role / profile information (login, email, name, and the extra information on profile)

Initial approach :

So armed with this, I went with the recommended approach of creating a UserProfile 1-to-1 object linked to user, provide the UserProfile with a choice field where the role is set (useful for knowing what i'm dealing with when calling get_profile() ) and subclassed UserProfile into ManagerUserProfile, EmployeeUserProfile, etc.

Problem :

That works for my needs in the frontend (outside of the admin), but setting the signal to create a UserProfile when a User is created is pointless since I don't know what kind of UserProfile should I create based only on user information.

What I'm aiming at is an atomic way of creating a particular User and it's corresponding EmployeeUserProfile/ManagerUserProfile at the same time, and having a neat admin representation.

Some of my ideas:

- Hide the UserAdmin and User Profile admins, create AdminModels for EmployeeUserProfile/Manager/etc and inline the User model. That way the person creating the users will see only a "New Manager" link with its corresponding fields. But they may create the UserProfile without a user ? How can i make this atomic ? How do i prevent from deleting the user within or make sure they provide all required info before allowing the profile to be saved ? -> Problem with this approach : I cannot seem to inline the user because it has no PK to UserProfile (it's the other way around).
- Again, hide UserAdmin, expose the subclassed profiles Admins, and reverse the signal. When a profile is created, create a corresponding user. But for this I need to be able to provide user fields (username, pass, email, etc) from profiles admin form.

Suggestions ?

Its my first app and maybe there's a neat way for this, but I haven't found it yet.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.
Cheers,
Zeta.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a custom form, custom admin view and use that for creating users in one request, with the exact logic you need. You can get an idea of how it's done by looking at django's own custom user creation process [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L89).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to implement what I needed. It may not be the cleanest, and it's open to suggestions, but it may help someone with a similar problem.

Since I needed to create only from the admin, I focused on that and build the following.

forms.py

```
class RequiredInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    """
    Generates an inline formset that is required
    """

    def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
        """
        Override the method to change the form attribute empty_permitted
        """
        form = super(RequiredInlineFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
        form.empty_permitted = False
        self.can_delete = False
        return form
```

models.py (i'm not using signals for automatically creating a profile on user creation)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Other fields here
    [.......]

    USER_TYPES = (
       ('manager', 'Manager'),
       ('employee', 'Employee'),
    )

    user_type = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


class EmployeeProfile(UserProfile):
    [...]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_type = 'employee'

class ManagerProfile(UserProfile):
    [...]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ManagerProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_type = 'manager'


class Manager(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        #app_label = 'auth'
        verbose_name = 'manager'
        verbose_name_plural = 'managers'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_staff = True
        super(Manager, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        g = Group.objects.get(name='Managers') 
        g.user_set.add(self)


class Employee(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        #app_label = 'auth'
        verbose_name = 'employee'
        verbose_name_plural = 'employees'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_staff = False
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        g = Group.objects.get(name='Employees') 
        g.user_set.add(self)
```

admin.py

```
class ManagerProfileAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ManagerProfile
    max_num = 1
    extra = 1
    formset = RequiredInlineFormSet


class EmployeeProfileAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = EmployeeProfile
    max_num = 1
    extra = 1
    formset = RequiredInlineFormSet

class ManagerAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """
    Options for the admin interface
    """
    inlines = [ManagerProfileAdmin]

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.filter(Q(userprofile__user_type='manager'))

        return qs


class EmployeeAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """
    Options for the admin interface
    """
    inlines = [EmployeeProfileAdmin]

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.filter(Q(userprofile__user_type='employee'))

        return qs

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(Manager, ManagerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```